# how can I rename a column from rails console without migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to rename a table column from the rails console without writing any migration.

how can I do that?

Comment: you should not do it without migration, its not best practice nor rails way.

Comment: I know this was a very pesky db out of sync problem...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
rails dbconsole
ALTER TABLE name RENAME column TO column
```

Comment: Just a side note @Boti, your `db/schema.rb` will not be updated using this method, which will potentially cause you problems when you deploy. If there's such a concern, you may want to run `rake db:schema:dump` after doing this so your schema file is synchronized with the current database structure (and naming).

Comment: OP asked about `rails console`, not db console. They are different consoles

Answer (score 46):

I opted to run this from the console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.rename_column :tablename, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
```

Comment: Best answer. It allows you to execute commands just like you would inside the Rails migration.

Answer (score -2):

1. you run in console: `rails g migration ChangeColName`
2. you edit the file db/migrate/"timestamp"_change_col_name.rb insert in def change -

   ```
   rename_column :tablename, :old_column_name, :new_column_name -save
   ```
3. you run in console: `rake db:migrate`  :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're confusing "console" with "terminal", but what the OP meant was how to do this in the actual rails console (the IRB interface) without writing / running a migration file.